# Handling promise rejection in ember-data with findQuery()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rsvp.js

I cannot seem to get ember-data to reject failed (404's) when using findQuery(..query..); find(..id..); works fine.

So in the route:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { post_id: model.get('slug') };
  },

  model: function(params){
    var query = {};
    query.slugs = params.post_id;
    return App.Post.findQuery(query).then( 
      function (data) {
        return data.get('firstObject');
      }, 
      function (error) {
        console.log('error');
        throw 'boom!';
      }
    )
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this.controllerFor('post').set('content', model);
  },

  events: {
    error: function (reason, transition) {
     console.log('Error!');
    }
  }

});
```

I have also tried this:

```
return App.Post.findQuery(query).then( function (data) {
  return data.get('firstObject');
}).then( null, function (error) {
  console.log('error');
  throw 'boom!';
});
```

No joy. I can see the request to the URL returning as 404, but the promises error is never triggered. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this still an issue? The code seems correct but it might be some other thing that would show itself if you had a JSBin/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's only a typo, but the `events` hash in your `PostRoute` should be called `events` you seam to have defined it as singular `event` this might be the problem why your `error` hook inside that hash not getting found and this not invoked:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  events: {
    error: function (reason, transition) {
      console.log('Error!');
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there! Yes, sadly that was just a typo. I have adjusted the example above. I have tracked this down to a problem with the implementation for findQuery, there is an open PR fixing the issue here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1096#issuecomment-22246022

Comment: @i0n, ok good to know, I saw you actually talking about this with Paul Chavard in the github notification emails, sorry I couldn't help at all.

Comment: @i0n @ intuitivepixel did you have any luck figuring this out? I've just [raised this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4461)